# How can I access <Application_Home>/Library/Caches from a bundle?

Tags: ios, caching, uiimage, nsbundle

My app downloads images from a server. I'd like to save those images to the Caches folder and then access them with `UIImage(named:...` for in-memory caching. Will `UIImage(named: "fileURL", in: NSBundle.mainBundle, compatibleWith: nil)` find the Caches folder or do I need to create a different bundle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't want to use a bundle for caches folder. You should use `NSFileManager` to get the path for the caches folder. For example, in Swift 2:

```
let fileURL = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    .URLForDirectory(.CachesDirectory, inDomain: .UserDomainMask, appropriateForURL: nil, create: false)
    .URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.jpg")

let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path!)
```

Or Swift 3:

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
    .url(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    .appendingPathComponent("test.jpg")

let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path)
```